# Regular expression for parsing ::number::sentence::

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How will a regex for validation (`::number::sentence::`) such values look like?

```
::1::some text::
::2::some text's::
::234::some's text's::
```

Comment: What would you like to extract and **what have you tried**?

Comment: Is regular expression a requirement? I bet it's not. Do not use regex. There's no need here.

Comment: I need not to extract but to validate that the string has an indicated formate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
^::([0-9]+)::((?:(?!::).)*)::$
```

Example code:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("::1::some text::", "::([0-9]+)::((?:(?!::).)*)::");
var groups = match.Groups;
string num = groups[1].ToString();
string text = groups[2].ToString();
```

explanation:

```
^ Begin of the string
:: 2x ':'
([0-9]+) Match group 1, the 0-9 digits, one or more
:: 2x ':'
((?:(?!::).)*) Match group 2, any one character that isn't ::, zero or more
:: 2x ':'
$ End of the string
```

The `((?:(?!::).)*)` requires a little more explanation... Let's peel it...

```
( ... ) the first '(' and last ')', match group 2
```

So now we have:

```
(?:(?!::).)*
```

so

```
(?: ... )* group without name (non capturing group) repeated 0 or more times. Its content will be put in match group 2 because it's in defined inside match group 2
```

composed of:

```
(?!::).
```

where

```
. is any character
```

BUT before "capturing" the "any character" make a check: `(?!::)` that the any character and the next one aren't `::` (it's called *zero-width negative lookahead*)

Answer (score 5):

You could use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) and avoid a regex completely if your string is as simple as this e.g.

```
var data = "::234::some's text's::".Split(new string[] { "::" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(data[0]); // 234
Console.WriteLine(data[1]); // some's text's
```

If you need to use it for validation you can still use the same logic as above e.g.

```
public bool Validate(string str)
{
    var data = str.Split(new string[] { "::" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    double n;
    return data.Length == 2 && Double.TryParse(data[0], out n) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data[1]);
}
...
bool valid = Validate("::234::some's text's::");
```

Comment: +1 for stop regexing everything

Comment: +1 because you want him to live an happy and uneventful life... Still... I would remove the RemoveEmptyEntries, so it's easier to check the correctness of the input (if you do it, remember to increase the indexes of the two "parts")

Comment: @xanatos I guess it depends on really what's important here, the format of the data or the data itself. In my example I am simply extracting the data and validating it in the order it is expected to be in.

Comment: Note: `condition ? some bool : false` can be rewritten as `(condition) && (some bool)`

Comment: @Nuffin ah nice improvement, less code the better - updated.